# Prevent overlapping async code execution

Tags: c#, async-await

I have read about async-await patterns and that `Mutex` is incompatible with asynchronous code so I wonder how to write the following method in a lightweight way, without object allocations (not even for a `Task<>`) but without excessive encumberance (from a pattern).

The problem is as follows. Look at this method:

```
    public async void SendAsync(Stream stream, byte[] data)
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(data.Length);
        await stream.WriteAsync(data);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
```

Now, this method probably is not very useful. In fact there is plenty more code, but for the problem at hand it's perfectly complete.

The problem here is that I have a single main thread that will invoke the method very quickly without `await`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    SendAsync(stream[i], buffer[i]);
}
```

All I want is that the main thread loops through quickly without blocking.

Now, this loop is looped over, too:

```
while (true)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        SendAsync(stream[i], buffer[i]);
    }

    // TODO: add a break criterion here
}
```

My suspicion (fear) is that a very chunky `buffer` (say 1 MB) on a congested `stream[i]` (yes, it's a TCP/IP `NetworkStream` underneath) may cause the `n`*th* invocation to occur before the preceding `n-1`*th* invocation was reentrant (*returned* from the invocation).

The two tasks will then interfere with each other.

---

I don't want any of these two solutions I've already discarded:

1. (Non-)Solution 1: Mutex

This will throw an exception because `Mutex` has thread affinity and async code is thread-agnostic:

```
    public async void SendAsync(Stream stream, byte[] data)
    {
        mutex.WaitOne(); // EXCEPTION!

        await stream.WriteAsync(data.Length);
        await stream.WriteAsync(data);
        await stream.FlushAsync();

        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

2. Solution 2: return a `Task` to `*.WaitAll()`

The loop is in consumer land while `SendAsync()` is in framework land, I don't want to force consumers to use an intricate pattern:

```
while (true)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = SendAsync(stream[i], buffer[i]);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    // TODO: add a break criterion here
}
```

Furthermore I don't ABSOLUTELY want `Task`s to be allocated on each loop, this code will run at a moderate frequency (5-10 Hz) with 1000+ open streams. I cannot allocate 10000+ objects per second, it would GC like crazy. Mind that this is minimal code per SO policy, the actual code is much more complex.

---

What I'd like to see is some kind of **outside-loop-allocation** that allows to wait for completion only when absolutely necessary (like a `Mutex`) but at the same time does not allocate memory inside the loop.

Comment: The consumer of your framework shall not modify buffers while the stream is sending them over the network... How do you prevent it ? Is the consumer required to insert fresh array instances (buffer considered as readonly) ?

Comment: Good point, this is another thing to take into account. But for performance reasons I don't want to copy it either. That would require another `byte[]` allocation. I have to think about this, too.

Comment: I don't know.  The question is a bit weird.  On the one hand, you want your loop to execute all method calls concurrently.  But on the other, you don't want the method calls to conflict with each other.  It seems a bit contradictory.  Why don't you start by benchmarking the simplest solution to the problem (having `SendAsync` return `Task` instead of void, and awaiting on it), before deciding what will or won't perform well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with reentrancy, just basic concurrency - you have no synchronization whatsoever, so there's plenty of things that can go wrong. Also, you *are* allocating tasks on each loop - what do you think those `WriteAsync` methods are returning? It's not like it matters anyway - I/O is orders of magnitude slower than GC and allocations. You're already allocating at least three tasks, do you really think a fourth one is going to make or break your application? Are you trying to write a real-time application, on .NET, on desktop Windows?

Comment: And I have to say that you're going to have much bigger issues with those 1000+ open streams - since it's obvious you're not using pre-allocated buffers, those are going to completely prevent heap compaction, which is pretty much going to kill your process with heap fragmentation. If you need a server like this, you need to know all those issues - there's plenty. It's very hard to code a good TCP server in .NET - make sure there's no simpler way to do what you're trying to do, and if there isn't, learn all the intricacies of the GC, handle pinning and TCP.

Comment: @sstan I want to send data concurrently on multiple streams. At the same time I don't want messages to interfere with each other on any single stream. That's not weird at all.

Comment: @Luaan First of all, thanks for the critique and pointers. It's not strictly RT but the server must be very reactive. It runs on Linux/Mono. The streams actually use pre-allocated buffers, that's why `SendAsync()` takes a `byte[]` that is filled by a binarizer similar to protobuf. The binarizer code is injected into `SendAsync()` and invoked inside the critical section (that is now protected with a semaphore). Really, it works perfectly fine now, tests passed all and performance is comparable/better than before! I'll remove allocation from `await`s on a second refactoring pass. Thanks all!!

Comment: Yeah, but when is that `byte[]` array allocated? Unless you have a pool of buffers allocated when your server starts, the problem is still there. The problem is that while the I/O operation is pending, the buffer is pinned, and prevents heap compaction. If you allocate the buffer when a new connection is accepted, you're going to have them all over the heap, ultimately causing worse and worse fragmentation, especially when you pretty much always have those I/O operations running.

Comment: @Luaan I understand your point (pinning/GC). Right now it's allocated by a remoting proxy object (one for each client/NetworkStream). I'll look into it, maybe a factory for the proxies could *eagerly* pre-allocate the buffers (*pooling*) and recycle them for new proxies avoiding *lazy* allocation on connection. I must first consider how much work this change would require. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a wrapper class over the stream, you could do something like this :

```
private Stream stream;
private Task currentTask;

public async void SendAsync(byte[] data)
{
    currentTask = WriteAsyncWhenStreamAvailable(data);
    await currentTask;
}

private async Task WriteAsyncWhenStreamAvailable(byte[] data)
{
    if (currentTask != null)
        await currentTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    await WriteAsync(data);
}

public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] data)
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await stream.WriteAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await stream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This way you always wait for the previous `WriteAsync` to end before sending the new data. This solution will ensure the buffers to be sent in requested order.

---

You could use an [async `SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `Mutex`

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public async void SendAsync(Stream stream, byte[] data)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // EXCEPTION!

    await stream.WriteAsync(data.Length);
    await stream.WriteAsync(data);
    await stream.FlushAsync();

    semaphore.Release();
}
```

---

**Beware of `OutOfMemoryException` if you blindlessly produce new data without taking in account the size of pending buffers...**

Comment: Both solutions are good on first look. But I guess that `ConfigureAwait()` may internally allocate a `new Task()`. The second solution looks very promising! I have benchmark code ready and will run it against the second solution. If it's close to the plain (unsafe) performance it will be perfectly fine!

Comment: @pid I think you should really look a lot deeper into how `async` and `Task`s work, especially if you're trying to optimize for performance (and actually making your code correct!). `ConfigureAwait` doesn't create a task, it creates some awaitable. On the other hand, *all those Async methods create a task*. They have to. `await` isn't simple, you need to know what you're doing - your guessing around isn't helping much. First, make sure your code is correct - right now, it simply isn't. Then, profile the code to see if it's fast enough for your use case, and find the bottlenecks if not.

Comment: The synchronized code runs at about 600-650 ticks. The async code without semaphore is about 280-300 ticks. The async code with the semaphore oscillates between 300-600 ticks, with an average around 350-400 ticks. That means under perfect conditions it has some 20 ticks overhead, which is acceptable. Under adverse conditions the semaphore must synchronize and performance falls back to the synchro-code, which is logic and understandable. Looking at code complexity, which is way less complex than TAP and similar. Thanks! That's what I hoped for. Must have overlooked `SemaphoreSlim` somehow...

Comment: @Luaan Yes, I concur. I'm at a very early stage of refactoring. The code used actual `Thread`s and must be converted to the async-await model. I'm learning as I go, because there's nowhere enough time I can dedicate to study, right now. I didn't expect `async` to remove magically all problems :) My idea is to write acceptable, correct code right now that does not degrade performance compared to the previous multithreaded implementation. Only then I'll have time to review it again and actually optimize for performance. "Performance" right now is just about "acceptable" compared to before. thx!